# New Task "Edit page" turns page blank

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-site

I've added a few jQuery scripts to our Sharepoint New Task page using webparts, the last of which was one that hid certain fields on the new task form. The code works, but now when I try to edit the page to work on some more code, the page loads and then turns blank. I am unable to click on anything to stop it from turning blank for the life of me. The only option available is to stop editing using the Page tab on the top left corner. Anybody have this issue before and can bail me out?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49508825

Use the webpart maintenance page which allows you to remove and manage web parts without visiting the page, the instructions are as below.

Lets say your page is example.com/sites/default.aspx add the query string ?contents=1 to the page it will take you to the manage web parts page you can remove the script editor web part from there.

The other way is to use SharePoint designer to remove the web part this will also help you achieve the same result.

answered Mar 27 '18 at 9:13
Guruparan Giritharan